# Exclude specific javascript files or themes from Asset Optimizer

Tags: sxa, sitecore-client

Is there a way to exclude specific JavaScript files from Asset Optimizer. I know you can globally turn off Asset Optimizer or even do it at a site level. Is there a way to do it a file level or even the theme level?

Comment: You can upload pre-optimized files and then turn off the Asset Optimizer for your site.

Comment: Unfortunately SXA has multiple javascript files in the base theme that are not in our code base since we are including it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no configuration to enable/disable asset optimization on a theme/file level. SXA Theming and the Asset Optimizer considers the files uploaded under Scripts and Styles for optimization and to load on the website. You need to upload your file outside this location and refer accordingly.